# Opening SQL connection

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have inherited software to maintain. The previous version used a third party Datagridview substitute that isn't compatible with versions of Windows from Vista on. In attempting to put Datagridviews in I have run into a problem with connecting to the database.

I am trying to make a small program to play around with connection and SELECT outside of the original software so I can further understand what I am doing and without going through the full process of using the original software to get to the testing point.

```
Private Shared Function GetData(ByVal sqlCommand As String) As DataTable

    Dim table As New DataTable()

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=true;" _
    & "AttachDbFilename=C:blah\blah\blah.mdf;User Instance=true;"

    Using con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using command = New SqlCommand(sqlCommand, con)
            Using da = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                da.Fill(table)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return table

End Function
```

My SQL command is a simple "Select * FROM Setup" and the rest of the program is form loads, imports, and DataGridView formatting. I don't think it affects the SQL part and would be cumbersome to include here.

This results in what appears to be a closed connection.

![Connection Property] https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOvdK.png

This is a screenshot of my SQLExpress which might help diagnose connection problems.

![SQL Properties] https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTZ8G.png

I've blurred out the computer name in grey, but I did notice that there was another computer name in pink. I don't know what it means other than maybe this database was originally created on another computer and has been copied and pasted.

Finally this is the connection string that the original software used:

```
"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\blah\blah\blah.mdf;Trust_Connection=Yes;"
```

I have also tried:

```
"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\blah\blah\blah.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;User Instance=true"
```

Finally, this is my exception:

```
"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\blah\blah\blah.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."
```

I got my alternate connection strings from www.connectionstrings.com.

Comment: you need to open the connection before filling the datatable

Comment: I added `con.Open()` and I still get the same exception only much faster.

Comment: From MSDN -> _The Fill method implicitly opens the Connection that the DataAdapter is using if it finds that the connection is not already open. If Fill opened the connection, it will also close the connection when Fill is finished._

Comment: That's what I thought which is why I think I may have deleted the con.Open() previously. Must have been another error somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `Open()` command.

```
con.Open()
```

Full code listing. (Also a good idea is to wrap your code in a `Try.... End Try` block).

```
Private Shared Function GetData(ByVal sqlCommand As String) As DataTable

    Dim table As New DataTable()

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=true;" _
    & "AttachDbFilename=C:blah\blah\blah.mdf;User Instance=true;"

    Using con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        conn.Open()
        Using command = New SqlCommand(sqlCommand, con)
            Using da = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                da.Fill(table)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return table

End Function
```

Comment: I still get the "Attempt to attach an auto-named..." error. It's saying attached as if I am trying to create a database or table when in reality I am trying to open one. Or am I reading too much into the error?

Comment: I found a typo after adding `con.Open()`! Thanks.